# Microsoft.Practices.Unity configuration issue - System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, .net, unity-application-block

I have implement the Microsoft unity application block in one of my project.

Project's Unity configuration file is:

```
<UnityConfiguration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
<container>
  <register type="IInputAdapterPoc" mapTo="InputAdapterPoc" />
</container>
<alias alias="IInputAdapterPoc" type="Company.Product.Pocc.IInputAdapterPoc,Company.Product.Pocc" />
<alias alias="InputAdapterPoc" type="Company.Product.Pocc.InputAdapterPoc,Company.Product.Pocc" />
```

Project's Interface and concreate class:

```
namespace Company.Product.Pocc
{
    public class InputAdapterPoc : BaseInputAdapter, IInputAdapterPoc
    {
        public override void Process(Connector _connector) { }
        public override void Intialize(Entity _entity) { }
    }
}

namespace Company.Product.Pocc
{
    public interface IInputAdapterPoc : IInputAdapter { }
}

namespace Company.Product.Interface
{
    public interface IInputAdapter : IAdapter
    {
        void Process(Connector connect);
    }
}

namespace Company.Product.Adapter
{
    public abstract class BaseInputAdapter : IInputAdapter
    {
        public abstract void Process(Connector connect);
        public abstract void Intialize(Entity entityMapping);
    }
}
```

Problem is - while executing the code:

```
var instance = new UnityContainer().Resolve<AnyType>();
```

it throws the Exception:

> Exception Type:
>   System.TypeInitializationException
>
> InnerException:
>   {"The type name or alias IInputAdapterPoc could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name."}

Message:

> The type initializer for 'Company.Product.Utility.UnityHelper' threw an exception.

How can I resolve this? Any idea?

Comment: I don't see any InputAdapterPocc (note "Pocc" instead of "Poc")) in your code, just fix your configuration file (2nd alias entry).

Comment: ahhh. yes. its a typo!! copy paste typo :-) Modified the question body.

Comment: Please re-read exception message: _"The type name or alias **IInputAdapterPocc** could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name."_ That typo is also in your true configuration file, not just in your question body

Comment: I suggest that you use unity fluent registration. It's much less error prone.

Comment: ok Adriano!!! fixed it. :-| but not able to fix the problem :-(